# how to run imacros .js from dos batch script or schedule

Tags: javascript, imacros

how to run the ".js" file from dos batch script or schedule it to run?

i can run .iim but is it possible to run .js file 
it will not run form dos batch script

```
c:>imacros.exe" -macro c:\testmacro.js
```

I can run the .iim file from dos command prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Pale Moon
start palemoon.exe
start /wait palemoon.exe imacros://run/?m="testmacro.js"
```

Save this code with extension *.bat or run each command one by one in Command Prompt.

CD is the Current Directory of the browser where you want to run the macro, for example I'm using Pale Moon, you can change it to firefox or whatever.

P.S.: This won't work in Imacros Browser, as it doesn't support *.js files by default.

Comment: ***** amazing ***** guys., such keen observation and attention to detail, perfect. i tried many options this solution worked perfect.

Comment: can you help me with this little tricky issue, i just need to fill the array automatically based on data on the page - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050793/imacros-javascript-multiple-for-loops-inner-loop-process-extract-data

Answer (score 2):

You can try to put .js file in bookmarks and grab the link.

The link looks like this.

```
imacros://run/?m=SomeScript.js
```

Then in .iim file put this code.

```
URL GOTO=imacros://run/?m=SomeScript.js
```

Then use your code to run .js file. It's a little bit longer method but it could work. I am sure there is a way to do it from batch file.