# imacros javascript multiple for loops inner loop process extract data

Tags: javascript, loops, imacros

i am trying to figureout a way to loop all countries.

I have below script it has 3 loops.Loop # 2, 3 working fine. but Loop #1 is not.
here is the logic - main alexa site www.alexa.com/topsites/countries and this has multiple countries each country has a 2 charecter suffix. for each country number is prefixing to get country listing.

process: 1. loop#1 go to www.alexa.com/topsites/countries and loop all countries.(this part does not work) 2.loop#2 for each country loop all pages(this part also working) 3. loop# 3 for each page collect data. (this part is working)

```
var jsLF="\n";

var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro += "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macro += "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macro += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
macro += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\   FILE=hiprsites.txt" + jsLF;

var macro1;
macro1  =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries;{{j}}/ID" + jsLF; 

var macroAllC;
macroAllC  =  "CODE:";
macroAllC +=  "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macroAllC +=  "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macroAllC +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macroAllC +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries;{{z}}" + jsLF; 


//LOOP #1
//loop all countries take one country and go to next loop
for (var z=0;z<200;z++)
{
iimDisplay(z);    
iimSet("z", z);
iimPlay(macroAllC);

//LOOP #2
//loop all the pages for each page get data
for (var j=0;j<20;j++)
{
iimDisplay(j);    
iimSet("j", j);
iimPlay(macro1);

//LOOP #3
//loop the current page and get all 25 result
for(var i=1;i<=25;i++)    
{
iimDisplay(i);    
iimSet("i", i);
iimPlay(macro);
iimSet("i",i);
}//loop individual pages
}//loop macro1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to extract all countries in a temporary array:

```
var countries = new Array(), i = 4;
do
{ 
iimDisplay("Extracting " + i);
iimSet("i", i);
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:*countries* EXTRACT=HREF");
  if(iimGetLastExtract()!='#EANF#')
      countries.push(iimGetLastExtract());
        else break;
i++;
}
while(i);
```

I'm setting `i=4` to get the first country `AF`

Then you will have to loop through each country page and extract all data in another temporary array:

```
for(i=0;i<countries.length;i++)
  {
   var j = 2;
   iimSet("url", countries[i]);
   iimPlay("CODE:URL GOTO={{url}}");

   do
    {
    iimDisplay("Loop " + (i+1) + " of " + countries.length + "\nExtracting " + j);
    iimSet("j", j);
    iimPlay("CODE:SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1\nTAG POS={{j}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:*siteinfo* EXTRACT=HREF");
     if(iimGetLastExtract()!='#EANF#')
        temp_pages.push(iimGetLastExtract());
         else
          {
           iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next");
            if(iimGetLastError()=='OK')
               j = 1;
                else
                 break;
           }
     j++;     
    }
  while(j);
 }
```

Now we have all pages from all countries stored in `temp_pages` array, which you will have to loop and extract the data you need:

```
for(i=0;i<temp_pages.length;i++)
     {iimDisplay("Loop " + (i+1) + " of " + temp_pages.length);
      iimSet("url", temp_pages[i]);
      iimPlay("CODE:URL GOTO={{url}}");
      j = 1;
 do
{
iimSet("j", j);
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=TXT");
 if(iimGetLastExtract()!='#EANF#')
   {
    iimSet("ext", iimGetLastExtract());
    iimPlay("CODE:SET !EXTRACT {{ext}}\nSAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\ FILE=hiprsites.txt");
 }
  else break;
  j++;
  }
   while(j);
}
```

As a result you will have in `hiprsites.txt` a lot of anchors (don't know why you need this information). If you want to extract `hrefs`, then change `TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=TXT` to `TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:* EXTRACT=HREF`.

Good Luck )

Comment: great work. that is exactly i am looking for. i will test it, i am sure it will work. i feel confident that we can do these kind of extractions. i have another imacro bothering me since few days. not sure what i am doing wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104425/is-this-possible-in-imacros-javascript-tried-many-ways-not-successful

Comment: can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152815/can-we-do-this-imacros-javascript-for-listbox-values-of-website-multi-level-cate

Answer (score 1):

try to review your code before you're posting the question to prevent such silly mistakes

```
var macroAllC;
macroAllC =  "CODE:";
macroAllC +=  "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macroAllC +=  "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macroAllC +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macroAllC +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.alexa.com/topsites/countries/{{z}}" + jsLF; 
var countries=new Array("RU","PK","GR");
for (var z=0;z<200;z++)
{
iimDisplay(z);    
iimSet("z", countries[z]);
iimPlay(macroAllC);
```

Comment: this is where the problem is. how do i handle {z} this variable? it expects 2 charecter codes to loop thru. is there a way to solve

Comment: you need to save all countries symbols in array and submit it as z. see example in my updated answer

Comment: it is hard to manually collect all the country codes and pass to array. i think we can automate this step to fill the arranty right.

Comment: see this: http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm . With a simple find an replace you can arrange you own array.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i will try to change script to save the list