# is this possible in imacros javascript ? tried many ways not successful

Tags: javascript, loops, macros, extract, imacros

i did everything handled. but no luck it is returning "undefined" data. i tried many differnt ways to get data from this site. not successful. I posted this in other forums no one able to solve this to handle full data extract.

i need data saved like this 91.228.53.28:8089 one per line all rows.

```
var jsLF="\n";
var ret,ret1,ret2,ret3,ret_val;


var p1; //open url
p1  =  "CODE:";
p1 +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-de/" + jsLF;

var p2; //extract 1st value ip save to tmp VAR1
p2  =  "CODE:";
p2 += "SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}}" + jsLF;
p2 += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
p2 += "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + jsLF;

var p3; //add constant value =":" Save to tmp VAR2
p3  =  "CODE:";
p3 += "SET !VAR2 :" + jsLF;
//p2 += "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + jsLF;

var p4; //extract port number
p4  =  "CODE:";
p4 += "TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;
p4 += "SET !VAR3 {{!EXTRACT}}" + jsLF;
p4 += "SET !EXTRACT NULL" + jsLF;

var p5final; //mer 3 parts to get final and save
p5final =  "CODE:";
p5final += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}" + jsLF;
p5final += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR2}}" + jsLF;
p5final += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR3}}" + jsLF;
p5final += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\  FILE=ip-address.csv" + jsLF;

//ADD !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}} // append! may be this is correct

ret = iimPlay(p1);
for(var i=1;i<=20;i=i+6) //1st loop extract 1st part of value
{
iimSet("i", i);
iimPlay(p2);
iimSet("i",i);

ret_val = iimGetExtract();
if(ret_val=="#EANF#" || ret_val=="undefined" || ret_val==null || ret_val=="" )
{
    iimSet("i",i+1);
}

ret1=iimPlay(p3); //extract 2nd part of value
iimSet("j",i+1);
ret2 = iimPlay(p4);   //extract 3rd part of value
iimSet("j",i+1);
ret3 = iimPlay(p5final); //write final concatinated value to file (Part1+part2+part3)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't store your variables anywhere. using `iimPlay()` erases every variable, is like starting over, so your final macro, the one that writes to the file doesn't know about `!VAR1, !VAR2` etc. You should do something like this:

```
var jsLF="\n";
var ret,ret1,ret2,ret3,ret_val;


var p1; //open url
p1  =  "CODE:";
p1 +=  "URL GOTO=http://www.proxynova.com/proxy-server-list/country-de/" + jsLF;

var p2; //extract 1st value ip save to tmp VAR1
p2  =  "CODE:";
p2 += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;

var p3; //add constant value =":" Save to tmp VAR2
p3  =  "CODE:";
p3 += "SET !VAR2 :" + jsLF;


var p4; //extract port number
p4  =  "CODE:";
p4 += "TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT" + jsLF;


var p5final; //mer 3 parts to get final and save
p5final =  "CODE:";
p5final += "ADD !EXTRACT {{myvar1}}" + jsLF;
p5final += "ADD !EXTRACT :" + jsLF;
p5final += "ADD !EXTRACT {{myvar2}}" + jsLF;
p5final += "SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\\  FILE=ip-address.csv" + jsLF;

ret = iimPlay(p1);
for(var i=1;i<=20;i=i+6) //1st loop extract 1st part of value
{
     iimSet("i", i);
     iimPlay(p2);
     iimSet("i",i);

     myvar1 = iimGetExtract();
     if(ret_val=="#EANF#" || ret_val=="undefined" || ret_val==null || ret_val=="" )
     {
         iimSet("i",i+1);
     }

     ret1=iimPlay(p3); //extract 2nd part of value
     iimSet("j",i+1);
     ret2 = iimPlay(p4);
     myvar2 = iimGetExtract();   //extract 3rd part of value
     iimSet("myvar1",myvar1);
     iimSet("myvar2",myvar2);
     ret3 = iimPlay(p5final); //write final concatinated value to file (Part1+part2+part3)
     }
```

Improve on this code I provided you and please don't ask the same question 2 times :) and always be careful where you put the `SET !EXTRACT NULL` (never on the end when you need the value in javascript)

Comment: you made my day. great help. you know how to build logic for imacros.

Answer (score 1):

In this article: http://tubes.io/blog/2013/08/28/web-scraping-javascript-heavy-website-keeping-things-simple/
It talks about extracting data with a lot of client side rendering.  If this doesn't help I think it might lead you to want you're missing. I can't view your site through the corporate filter... :(