# can we do this imacros javascript for listbox values of website multi level categories

Tags: javascript, loops, drop-down-menu, listbox, imacros

i am not sure where to start. i have a website where data is stored in list box controls. If i use "TXTALL" tag i can save list values.

1st step is to collect list of "_s_brand" manufacturers and store it in a array
2nd step is to collet 2nd level families - "_s_name" and store it in arrany for each "_s_brand" manufacturer
3rd step is to collect series for each "_s_brand" and for each "_s_name"
4th step is to final setp is for each "_s_brand" and for each "_s_name" and for each collect "_s_model" values

started script as below.

```
var jsLF = "\n";
var macro1;
macro1  =  "CODE:";
macro1 +=  "VERSION BUILD=9002379" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "TAB T=1" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + jsLF; 
macro1 +=  "URL GOTO=http://smartparts.co.uk/" + jsLF;
macro1 +=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/catalog/?left_selector=1 ATTR=NAME:brand EXTRACT=TXTALL"

var s_brand = new Array()

iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ACTION:/catalog/?left_selector=1 ATTR=NAME:brand EXTRACT=TXTALL");
if (iimGetLastExtract()!='#EANF#')
   s_brand.push(iimGetLastExtract());

iimDisplay (s_brand);
```

it is dumping all data into the array. how to seperate elements here so that if i loop "s_brand" i will get individual brands.

after i seperate how do i use them to go to next level of sub category

Comment: some how if we figure out how to parse TXTALL data and send to array sequentially we may get this extracted

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use JS.

Useful features are.

```
s_brand=s_brand .toString();
```

This way you can convert array into string and do methods like

```
split()
replace()
match()
search()
```

When you look into the array as a text you can use split() on `_s_brand` and get brands.

And try to use this method

```
//convert text into array
some_array=some_array.split("keyword");

//loop through array
for(var i = 0; i < some_array.length ; i++)
{

//do something

alert(some_array[i]);

}
```

Combining the above and regular expressions you can extract what you want form the text.

I hope this helps.

Comment: do you have some examples of                                                     split()
replace()
match()
search()

Comment: I wrote in my post a good example. The way you split text in 1 keyword that appears more times in the text. That way you will make an array. And when you loop through that array you can use one of those 4 methods to get what you want.

Comment: can you provide reference link in your posts. i searched but could not find example you mentioned in your posts